# Copy local array is faster than array from arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, optimization

While optimizing some code I discovered some things that I didn't expected.
I wrote a simple code to illustrate what I found below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int globalArr[1024][1024];

void initArr(int arr[1024][1024])
{
    memset(arr, 0, 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(int));
}


void run()
{
    int arr[1024][1024];
    initArr(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j)
        {
            globalArr[i][j] = arr[i][j];
        }

    }
}

void run2(int arr[1024][1024])
{
    initArr(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1024; ++j)
        {
            globalArr[i][j] = arr[i][j];
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            run();
        }
        auto duration = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        cout << "(run) Total time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(duration).count() << " microseconds\n";
    }

    {
        auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            int arr[1024][1024];
            run2(arr);
        }
        auto duration = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        cout << "(run2) Total time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(duration).count() << " microseconds\n";        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I build the code with g++ version 6.4.0 20180424 with -O3 flag.
Below is the result running on ryzen 1700.

```
(run) Total time: 43493 microseconds
(run2) Total time: 134740 microseconds
```

I tried to see the assembly with godbolt.org (Code separated in 2 urls)

https://godbolt.org/g/aKSHH6

https://godbolt.org/g/zfK14x

But I still don't understand what actually made the difference.

So my questions are:
1. What's causing the performance difference?
2. Is it possible passing array in argument with the same performance as local array?

Edit:
Just some extra info, below is the result build using O2

```
(run) Total time: 94461 microseconds
(run2) Total time: 172352 microseconds
```

Edit again:
From xaxxon's comment, I try remove the initArr call in both functions. And the result actually run2 is better than run

```
(run) Total time: 45151 microseconds
(run2) Total time: 35845 microseconds
```

But I still don't understand the reason.

Comment: One important point: you shouldn't measure both functions in one run. Make that 2 binaries and run them separately. Just swapping the order of functions can change the time significantly, just because of caching, likely also for other reasons (page faults?).

Answer (score 4):

> 1. What's causing the performance difference?

The compiler has to generate code for `run2` that will continue to work correctly if you call

```
run2(globalArr);
```

or (worse), pass in some overlapping but non-identical address.

If you allow your C++ compiler to inline the call, *and it chooses to do so*, it'll be able to generate inlined code that knows whether the parameter really aliases your global. The out-of-line codegen still has to be conservative though.

> 2. Is it possible passing array in argument with the same performance as local array?

You can certainly fix the aliasing problem in C, using the [`restrict`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) keyword, like

```
void run2(int (* restrict globalArr2)[256])
{
    int (* restrict g)[256] = globalArr1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 256; ++j)
        {
            g[i][j] = globalArr2[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

(or probably in C++ using the non-standard extension `__restrict`).

This should allow the optimizer as much freedom as it had in your original `run` - *unless* it's smart enough to elide the local entirely and simply set the global to zero.

Comment: Many compilers support `__restrict` for C++ functions as well, even though that's not in the language.

Comment: g++ seems to have __restrict__ keyword. 
I tried to follow your code, but doesn't make any difference on the result.

And I understand the generated code of run2 will be different of run. But what I don't understand is which part of the assembly made the performance difference?

Comment: @xaxxon yes, a simple virtue of being an answer and not a comment. As well as being quite richer. However, I doubt it is correct.

Comment: gani - the code you compiled to assembly in godbolt doesn't match the code you timed, so it's hard to say if it's comparable. @Frax - I think the observations about aliasing are _correct_, I'm just not sure they're sufficient to explain the difference.

Comment: @Useless Thanks for _correction_ (pun intended). My wording was very bad. Of course I meant what you said: while the observation itself is correct, it's likely not a correct explanation for the performance difference.